how to check and uncheck all Shadcn checkbox
I am building a React project using ShadCN components and want to implement a "Select All" checkbox functionality.
However, I want to achieve this without using hooks (e.g., useState or useReducer).
I am looking for a way to do this using plain Shadcn parametres .
My goal is to avoid using hooks and still manage the "checked" state for all checkboxes efficiently.
    import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Checkbox } from "@/components/ui/checkbox";

const CheckboxList = () => {
  const items = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"];
  const [checkedItems, setCheckedItems] = useState<boolean[]>(items.map(() => false));
  const [isAllChecked, setIsAllChecked] = useState(false);

  // Toggle "Select All" checkbox
  const handleSelectAll = () => {
    const newCheckedState = !isAllChecked;
    setIsAllChecked(newCheckedState);
    setCheckedItems(items.map(() => newCheckedState));
  };

  // Toggle individual checkboxes
  const handleItemChange = (index: number) => {
    const updatedCheckedItems = [...checkedItems];
    updatedCheckedItems[index] = !updatedCheckedItems[index];
    setCheckedItems(updatedCheckedItems);

    // Update "Select All" checkbox based on individual states
    const allSelected = updatedCheckedItems.every((item) => item);
    setIsAllChecked(allSelected);
  };

  return (
    <div className="p-4">
      {/* Select All Checkbox */}
      <div className="mb-2">
        <Checkbox
          checked={isAllChecked}
          onCheckedChange={handleSelectAll}
          id="select-all"
        />
        <label htmlFor="select-all" className="ml-2">
          Select All
        </label>
      </div>

      {/* Individual Checkboxes */}
      {items.map((item, index) => (
        <div key={index} className="mb-1">
          <Checkbox
            checked={checkedItems[index]}
            onCheckedChange={() => handleItemChange(index)}
            id={`item-${index}`}
          />
          <label htmlFor={`item-${index}`} className="ml-2">
            {item}
          </label>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CheckboxList;

Can someone suggest another approach
